# Switch visibility in php if parameter

Tags: php

I'm wondering if its possible to switch the visibility in PHP. Let me demonstrate:

```
class One {

     function __construct($id){

       if(is_numeric($id)){

          //Test function becomes public instead of private.

       }

     }


    private function test(){

       //This is a private function but if $id is numeric this is a public function

    }

}
```

Is such thing even possible?

Comment: This is not possible. Better explain why do you need this?

Comment: It makes no sense to do that

Comment: Well I was mostly curious. Thanks for the answer guys!

Comment: Just make it public and throw an exception if it is not numeric, when you expect it to be numeric.

Comment: Yea thats my idea. As said, I was just being curious if there is another way. ;)

Comment: You could use an abstract class or interface and then create two classes: one for numeric and one for non-numeric. Use a generator to create an instance of the implementing class depending on the id.

Comment: You can [use the reflection classes](http://www.webtipblog.com/unit-testing-private-methods-and-properties-with-phpunit/) to change the accessibility of a method, but I think it would still have to be called through the reflection methods, so I don't think you could do it exactly as you want. I haven't played with the reflection classes a lot, though. This kind of trickery should only really be used to enable unit testing.

Comment: @MattGibson - That [seems to be the case](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setaccessible.php#110414). Good highlight anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an abstract class with two implementing classes: One for numeric and one for non-numeric:

```
abstract class One {

    static function generate($id) {
        return is_numeric($id) ? new OneNumeric($id) : new OneNonNumeric($id);
    }

    private function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

}

class OneNumeric extends One {

    private function test() {

    }

}

class OneNonNumeric extends One {

    public function test() {

    }

}

$numeric = One::generate(5);
$non_numeric = One::generate('not a number');

$non_numeric->test(); //works
$numeric->test(); //fatal error
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be faked up to a point with [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods):

```
<?php

class One {
    private $test_is_public = false;

    function __construct($id){
        if(is_numeric($id)){
            $this->test_is_public = true;
        }
    }

    private function test(){
        echo "test() was called\n";
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments){
        if( $name=='test' && $this->test_is_public ){
            return $this->test();
        }else{
            throw new LogicException("Method $name() does not exist or is not public\n");
        }
    }
}

echo "Test should be public:\n";
$numeric = new One('123e20');
$numeric->test();

echo "Test should be private:\n";
$non_numeric = new One('foo');
$non_numeric->test();
```

I haven't thought about the side effects. Probably, it's only useful as mere proof of concept.